# How to evaluate the quality of PCA returned by torch.pca_lowrank()?

Tags: pytorch, data-science, linear-algebra, pca, precision-recall

I use the following piece of code:

```
U, S, V = torch.pca_lowrank(A, q=self.n_components)
self.V = V
self.projection = torch.matmul(A, V)
```

How to compute the cumulative percent variance or any other accuracy metric (single value between 0 and 100%) based on the above values returned? It's ok to project the matrix back with

```
approx = torch.matmul(self.projection, self.V.T)
```

if that helps with computing the metric.

I don't mind using other packages compatible with PyTorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulative percent variance as the ratio between the total variance of the reduced dimension matrix and the total variance of the original matrix.

```
total_var = torch.var(A)

total_var_approx = torch.var(approx)

cumulative_percent_variance = (total_var_approx / total_var) * 100
```